# React route returns nothing?

Tags: html, reactjs

I want to add a **conditional** route in my component, so if a **user** is **logged** in I return the component, and if not I want to navigate to the login page.

When I do that nothing is displayed on my page. How to manage it correctly?

```
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { UserContext } from '../UserContext';
import Login from './Login';
import React, { useContext } from 'react'

function ShoppingList() {
const  { user }  = useContext(UserContext);
if (user) {
return (
..... //content
);
}
else {
    return (
      <div>
        <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
      </div>
      );
  }
}
export default ShoppingList;
```

I tried also `Navigate` but I got an error and the same thing with the `history`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define your `Route` simply without any problem but adding a **custom hook** or any other implementation of an **authentication** checker will help you.

for example, you can check your user's auth and other information in the above function and send him to the `login` page.

```
// rest of the codes ...
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'

function ShoppingList() {
   // rest of the codes ...

   const history = useHistory();

   if(user.status !== 'loggedIn'){ // ---> example login checker
        history.push('/loign')
   }

    return (
      <div>
        <Route path='/home' component={home}/>
        // other routes
        <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
      </div>
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// forward
if (!user) return <Login />
return (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/some-path" component={SomeComponent} />
    ....
  </Switch>
)
```

```
// redirect
const AuthRoute = (props)=> {
   const user = useContext(UserContext);
   if (!user) return <Redirect to="/login" />
   return <Route {...props} />
}
const Main = ()=> {
 return (
  <Switch>
    <AuthRoute path="/some-path" component={SomeComponent} />
    <Route path="/login" component={Component} />
  </Switch>
 )
}
```